# For which $k$ is ${n \choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k} < \epsilon$?

Tags: probability

If $X$ ~ Binomial$(n,p)$, I am trying to find "the number of successes we need to observe such that we can be reasonably sure that there will be no more successes." This corresponds to the positive integer $k$ such that $$P(X > k|X\geq k) < \epsilon $$ 
Since $$P(X=i | X \geq k) = {n-k \choose i}p^k(1-p)^{n-k-i}$$ we must find $k$ as a function of $\epsilon$ such that $$\sum_{i=k+1}^{n} {n-k \choose i}p^k(1-p)^{n-k-i} < \epsilon$$

Can I have a hint for a clean way to compute the above? Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps try a normal distribution and the central limit theorem?

Comment: Although $P(X > k|X\geq k) < \epsilon$ is well-defined, it does NOT correspond to your idea of "the number of successes we need to observe such that we can be reasonably sure that there will be no more successes." When you are observing $X$ as a Binomial r.v. you get just one number, and there's no such thing as "more" or  "no more" success that are about to come. If you are observing iid Bernoulli trials coming one at a time, the by definition the trials are independent and the next trial is always gonna be the same as any of the previous ones.

Comment: If your Bernoulli trials are dependent or non-identical, then they don't directly sum to the Binomial as usual and you need some special model to have a Binomial, which parameter $n$ will not be the number of trials and the $p$ will not be your Bernoulli success chance.

Comment: On the other hand, if you take a Binomial r.v. that came from iid Bernoulli and decompose it to observe only the subset such that you can be conditioning on $X \geq k$, then by construct you know for sure that "there are more successes to come" beyond $X = k$, since $X = k$ is the minimum of the subset you're observing.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin Sorry, I should've clarified; the context is, individuals in a population have some property with probability $p$, independently of one another. Intuitively, if we observe (through sampling) that $k$ members of the population have the property, then it shouldn't be the case that the probability that $k+1$ members have the property is equal to the probability that $1$ member has the property. That is, I don't think this process is memoryless.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin "If you are observing iid Bernoulli trials coming one at a time, the by definition the trials are independent and the next trial is always gonna be the same as any of the previous ones." It sounds like you're saying that the binomial distribution is memoryless, which it isn't. What am I interpreting incorrectly here?

Comment: It seems you don't know what a [Bernoulli trial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial) (or [Bernoulli distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution)) is and you don't know the [relation between](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution#Related_distributions) Binomial and Bernoulli. Similarly, you throw the terms "independent" and "memoryless" around while now knowing what they refer to. StackExchange is not the place for free discussion, and more comments would be digressing further from your question post (which is mathematically well-defined).

Comment: If you want to know why your idea is not represented by that conditional probability expression, according to how you phrase things in the comments, my opinion is that you should make another question post specifically about that.